# Self-balancing robot

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, socket.io

I am building a 3D printed self-balancing robot, and use the attached server script to control it. I coded using node.io, express and socket.io.

The system is working, but I would appreciate some coding suggestions as I am quite new to these programming framework, and I would love to understand how to improve my knowledge of this domain.

In particular I would like your feedback on:

- Best practices and application design
- Performances and resources utilization of the Raspberry Pi
- Correctness in unanticipated cases

The setup is:

- Raspberry Pi running the node server and connected via USB serial to Arduino Mega
- Android tablet as remote to set several parameters of the robot such as switching the motors on and off and also receive data from the robot
- Arduino Mega to control the balancing, to read sensors etc

The folder structure is:

> ```
> \server
>   \-public
>       \-css
>                 \-js
>                 \-foundation
>                 \-[other self-contained frameworks]
>
>   [html files]
>         \scripts
> robotserver.js
> ```

Just for curiosity, here is a [video of the robot](https://plus.google.com/100167667322123716067/posts/ChcCAh6PCS9).

**robotserver.js**

```
// Variables for serial port
var com = require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serialport");
var serPort = "/dev/ttyACM0";
var serBaud = 38400;

//Container for data from Arduino
var ArduRead = new Object();
{
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDKp'] = 0;
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDKi'] = 0;
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDKd'] = 0;
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDAggKp']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDAggKi']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_APIDAggKd']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_SPIDKp']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_SPIDKi']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_SPIDKd']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_Yaw']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_Roll']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_Pitch']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_MotorsON']='False';
ArduRead['READ Read_LoopT']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_SetsteerGain']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_SetthrottleGain']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_TriggerAngleAggressive']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_Info']='',
ArduRead['READ Read_anglePIDOutput']=0;
ArduRead['READ Read_LMO'] = 0;
ArduRead['READ Read_RMO'] = 0;
}

var serialPort = new com.SerialPort(serPort, {
  baudrate: serBaud,
  parser: com.parsers.readline('\n')
  });

serialPort.on('open',function() {
  console.log('Arduino connected on '+ serPort + ' @' + serBaud);
});

//Read input from Arduino and stores it into a dictionary
serialPort.on('data', function(data, socket) {
    if (data.match(/ /g) && data.match(/READ/g))
    {
      var tokenData = data.split(" ");                                        
      ArduRead[tokenData[0] + ' ' + tokenData[1]]=tokenData[2] ;                                      
      //console.log(ArduRead[tokenData[0] + ' ' + tokenData[1]]);
    }

});
//--------------------------------------

var serverPort = 54321;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Routers
{
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('/public/chat.html');
  res.end;
});

//This is to serve the remote to be coded in Foundation
app.get('/found', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/foundation/index.html');
  res.end;
});

//Serves Yaw Pitch Roll gauge
app.get('/ypr', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/ypr2.htm');
  res.end;
});

//Serves Temp and battery gauge 
app.get('/tb', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/tempbatt.htm');
  res.end;
});

//Serves Virtual joystick
app.get('/vj', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/robotj.html');
  res.end;
});

//execute script to start viedo feed
app.get('/VIFE', function(req, res) {
  var postData = req.url;  
  postData = postData.replace("/VIFE?", "");
  function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
  exec('sudo bash /home/pi/Documents/Sketches/Bailey/server/' + postData, puts);
  console.log(postData);  
  res.end;
});

//Reads data from Arduino via ArduRead data structure
app.get('/READ', function(req, res) {
  var postData = req.url;  
  postData = postData.replace("?", " ");
  postData = postData.replace("/", "");
//console.log(req.url+ ' ' + ArduRead[postData.toString()]);  
  res.write(req.url+ ' ' + ArduRead[postData.toString()]);
  res.end();
});

//Sends a command to Arduino, find a better way to use format the string!
app.get('/SCMD', function(req, res) {
  var postData = req.url;  
  postData = postData.replace("?", " ");
  postData = postData.replace("/", "");
  postData = postData.replace("_", " ");
  postData = postData.replace("=", " ");
  serialPort.write(postData + '\n');
  res.end();

});

}

// Logging middleware goes here

// 'ping' and 'chat message' events are for debug purposes

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('New socket.io connection - id: %s', socket.id);
  setInterval(function(){
  socket.emit('status', ArduRead['READ Read_Yaw'], ArduRead['READ Read_Pitch'], ArduRead['READ Read_Roll']);
  }, 200);
  socket.on('ping', function(data, data2){console.log('event: ', data2);});

  socket.on('move', function(dX, dY){

    //console.log('event: ', dX, dY);
    serialPort.write('SCMD Steer ' + dX + '\n');
    serialPort.write('SCMD Throttle ' + -1*dY + '\n');

    });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log(msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Disconnected id: %s', socket.id);
  });  

});

io.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + hs.sessionID 
            + ' disconnected!');
    });

http.listen(serverPort, function(){
  console.log('listening on *: ', serverPort);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know quickly this:

```
  postData = postData.replace("/VIFE?", "");
  function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
  exec('sudo bash /home/pi/Documents/Sketches/Bailey/server/' + postData, puts);
```

This is incredibly dangerous, anybody with some some basic hacking knowledge can take complete control of your machine. I hope this server is not connected to the internets.

Comment: thanks, the raspberry is not connected to the Internet. Can you suggest a better way to execute bash scripts from node.io?

Comment: @Paolo I am thinking about it..